# How to configure IoC container by code for certain task

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have a function, `MyFunc`, that receives an `IDoer`. I want to pass different implementations and different initializations:

```
var types = new IDoer[]{typeof(Walker),typeof(Runner),typeof(Sweamer)};
var strings = new[]{"abc","xyz","zoo","cat","dog"};

foreach(var type in types) {
    foreach(var str in strings) {
        IDoer doer = container.ResolveWithParams(type, str, RandomizeInteger());            
        MyFunc(doer, str);
    }
}
```

or even better:

```
var strings = new[]{"abc","xyz","zoo","cat","dog"};

foreach(var type in types) {
    foreach(var str in strings) {
        IDoer doer = container.ResolveWithParams<Walker>(type, str, RandomizeInteger());
        MyFunc(doer, str);
        doer = container.ResolveWithParams<Runner>(type, str, RandomizeInteger());
        MyFunc(doer, str);
        doer = container.ResolveWithParams<Sweamer>(type, str, RandomizeInteger());
        MyFunc(doer, str);
    }
}
```

for instance, `Walker`'s constructor is:

```
public Walker(/*lots of params...*/, 
              string importantString, /*other params...*/, 
              int importantInteger,/*even more params...*/)  {/*...*/}
```

`Runner`'s is:

```
public Runner(string importantString, /*some params...*/, 
              int importantInteger,/*additional different set of data...*/)  {/*...*/}
```

and `Sweamer`'s:

```
public Sweamer(string importantString, int importantInteger) {/*...*/}
```

My question is how to configure this `container` using code (no XML) ?

I don't mind which kind of container - it's just my first steps using IoC containers, and I want to learn in general how it's being done.

Comment: Does this URL help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx

Comment: Specifically, look at point "5" in Egor4eg's link: `If you want to create more than one registration or mapping for the same type, you can create a named (non-default) mapping by specifying a name as a parameter` Give each one a unique name then call them out by that name.

Comment: @Egor4eg: I thought initially - yes, but the parameter is the type. I don't want that. I want the parameter to be the input-parameters. I'd rather move problems to compilation stage...

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: if you're referring to [5th example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx#code-snippet-5), than see my comment to [@Egor4eg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807703/how-to-configure-ioc-container-by-code-for-certain-task#comment25983725_17807703). I want to receive the parameters dynamically, not the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with enterprise library unity container you can do this

```
    container.RegisterType<ITestClass, TestClass1>("TestClass1");
    container.RegisterType<ITestClass, TestClass2>("TestClass2");

    var class0 = new TestClass3();
    container.RegisterInstance<ITestClass>(class0);

    var class1 = container.Resolve<TestClass1>();
    var class2 = container.Resolve<TestClass2>();
    var class3 = container.Resolve<ITestClass>("TestClass1");
    var class4 = container.Resolve<ITestClass>("TestClass3");
```

to pass up parameter for the constructor if the element is an injected value don't do anything else use a collection of ParameterOverride

```
    ...Resolve<TestClass1>(new []{
          new ParameterOverride("str", str),
          new ParameterOverride("num", RandomizeInteger())});
```

Where "str" and "num" are the property names for the constructor.

assumming the constructor is

```
public TestClass1(string str, int num)
```

this example uses magic strings and its bad to use it but is the closes to your example.
NOTE: the example testclass3 it always returns the same instance.

Comment: I don't understand from this example how do I pass the `str` and the `RandomizeInteger()` parameters from the container to the concrete types' constructors... ?

Comment: I don't understand do you want the container to generate a new instance with the values or to get the already generated instance with have the values you want?

Comment: I want the the container to generate a new instance, but to pass to the constructor of this new instance the `str` and `RandomizeInteger()` (for instance) parameters

Comment: @Tal I edited the answer to pass the parameters to the constructor.

Comment: this is nice! was hoping for something that resolves implicitly by type (by the fact that it's a string and an integer), not having to type parameter names explicitly, but if that's the best I can get, then that's it. Do you have an idea how it can be done in other `IoC`s like `Ninject`/`Windsor`/other ?

Comment: no and really the passing things to the constructor is not a good idea you can easily generate them inside the specific implementation or have them as parameters that you pass after the instantiation of the object, if all of them have it you can even put it in the interface.